# How to hide neovim lsp process massage

Tags: autocomplete, neovim, pylsp

iam using neovim config from https://github.com/jdhao/nvim-config
it's working good, but unfortunately iam using Termux (Android) and I was quite disturbed by the process message in the bottom right corner, is there a way to remove it?

I wish there was a way to get rid of that process message

[screenshot from my phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPP2m.jpg)